# insert data to mysql db table

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, database, tabs

I'm trying to insert data to my table in mysql db but again it send just null to my table instead of data.
this is my table fields:

```
MySQL [Alora]> desc car_list;
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| model_name     | varchar(40) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| price          | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| vehicle_milage | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.009 sec)
```

and my code snippet:

```
def send_data (model_name, price, vehicle_milage):
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect (user='root', password='root', host='localhost', database='Alora')

    cursor = cnx.cursor ()


    cursor.execute ('INSERT INTO car_list VALUES (model_name, price, vehicle_milage)')

    cnx.commit ()

    cursor = cnx.cursor ()
```

but after i run it my table is just look like this:

```
MySQL [Alora]> SELECT * FROM car_list;
+------------+-------+----------------+
| model_name | price | vehicle_milage |
+------------+-------+----------------+
| NULL       | NULL  | NULL           |
| NULL       | NULL  | NULL           |
+------------+-------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

what should i do to send it correctly to my table?

Answer (score 1):

I think your `cursor.execute ('INSERT INTO car_list VALUES (model_name, price, vehicle_milage)` is wrong.

You tell to insert empty rows. It has to look like this:

```
INSERT INTO car_list (model_name, price, vehicle_milage) VALUES ('BMW', 'thousend', 'test')
```

Comment: again it send Null to table

Comment: try to add `cursor.close()`